# Osclass 3.5.3 - The page is not redirecting properly

Tags: php, osclass

I've got problem with Osclass 3.5.3 with searching by parameters. When I go into category for example "For Sale" and try search by City or Price or something else. After click Apply, my browser return me redirecting error like this:

![http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5O27KBptBeY/hqdefault.jpg][1]

The link which is generated after click Apply button looks like this:

```
localhost/index.php?page=search&sOrder=dt_pub_date&iOrderType=desc&sCategory=1&sCategory[]=1
```

Even if I search for empty fields the result is the same.

I checked in another browser ->  without result.

I've got the same error at localhost and hosting server.

Somebody know how to fix it?

BRegards.

Comment: Link to screen: http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5O27KBptBeY/hqdefault.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Hello i am not an expert but i had the same problem, what i did was i corrected the rules. the mistake was mine from the beguining i had chaged pattern to padrão and because of that they were not working.
If you let the rules as default or if you change them without having special characters it will work. my website is [achei.pt](http://www.achei.pt)